# Android. How to store data for database correctly?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am developing an app which after installation has to insert into database a big massive of data (about 5 Mb). But before to start inserting data, first app has to get these data somewhere. For that I created a class where I store all data into arrays. Below I give an example:

```
public class Data {
    public static String[] table_1 = {"text1","text2","text3","text4"..."text500"};
    public static String[] table_2 = {"text1","text2","text3","text4"..."text356"};
    public static String[] table_3 = {"text1","text2","text3","text4"..."text485"};
..........................
    public static String[] table_35 = {"text1","text2","text3","text4"..."text267"};
}
```

Than in `onCreate()`, app loops through all these arrays and inserts data into database. But here I encounter with problem called: **error: code too large.** I know that cause of problem is `Data` class because code is limited to 64K bytes. I thought to separate data between two classes, but I don't think its a good idea.

So, my question is how correctly to store data for database. What can you advise in this situation ?

Comment: Did you consider writing the data into a CSV file, and implement reading it and storing the data as part of the "first run" of the app ?

Comment: Yes, I considered it, but how than I will determine the length of table. With arrays I can get the length of array and so control my insertions, when the first array is finished, I start insert into second table data from the second array and so on.

Comment: You can use multiple csv/xml/json files to read the data in case you need to partition it for any reason (which I don't really understand why).

Comment: alfasin, what about speed ? what faster read data from file or from array ?

Comment: The speed of loading of the data is irrelevant since it happens only once in the beginning of the programing, in a backgroud thread...

Answer (score 0):

you can load that content from a xml file, and once loaded do your insert statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLite database .
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: And who will insert the data into SQLLite to begin with ? remember that this DB is local on the user's phone...

Answer (score 0):

two ways:

1. load that content from the internet and store it in your local SQLite database.
2. Create a File e.g. XML or Txt File with JSON string. Place it inside of your APK and load that file in your application and persist your text. But maybe it is not required to persist that text in your database because you can use your xml file as static data storage too.